# using google map in mvc to get the routes by click on the map to define start/end

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to develop an application in mvc ,in this application the user is able to define its start and end location to travel ,i am so new in google map .this ability should be very user friendly .

The map should appear on the screen and the user able to click on the map to define the start and end location of her/his travel .

I found a sample that the user can input her/his start end location in the textbox as you can see here :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

    function InitializeMap() {
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
        var myOptions =
        {
            zoom: 8,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directionpanel'));

        var control = document.getElementById('control');
        control.style.display = 'block';


    }



    function calcRoute() {

        var start = document.getElementById('startvalue').value;
        var end = document.getElementById('endvalue').value;
        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });

    }



    function Button1_onclick() {
        calcRoute();
    }

    window.onload = InitializeMap;
    </script>

<table id ="control">
<tr>
<td>
<table>
<tr>
<td>From:</td>
<td>
    <input id="startvalue" type="text" style="width: 305px" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>To:</td>
<td><input id="endvalue" type="text" style="width: 301px" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align ="right">
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="GetDirections" onclick="return Button1_onclick()" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign ="top">
<div id ="directionpanel"  style="height: 390px;overflow: auto" ></div>
</td>
<td valign ="top">
<div id ="map" style="height: 390px; width: 489px"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</html>
```

But i need to define his/her start end location by clicking on the map ,this code can be changed and the textboxs change two click mode in this code?

Best regards